# I took a Word to Work with Me #3

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, humor

I took a word to work with me,
And it made me feel quite chill.
But after I mixed it up to some degree,
The wooziness began to fill

So I mixed it up - I took away
And it helped me get back home.
I was prescribed some dice to take today
And let it loose full blown!

---

What's the word?

---

**Hints**

> 1. Enlightenment comes from within - or inside

> 2. Death always comes together, but shortened

> 3. If you're having trouble, call me on 3547!

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible the word is:

> Tranquil

I took a word to work with me,
And it made me feel quite chill.

> By definition, one who is tranquil is calm and relaxed.

But after I mixed it up to some degree,
The wooziness began to fill

> Tranquil anagrams to [Quantril](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzquinamide), which is brand of a discontinued drug that was used to treat vomiting and nausea. Would probably make you feel a bit woozy...

So I mixed it up - I took away
And it helped me get back home.

> If you anagram again, and take away some letters you can find Rail, Trail or Train - all potentially helpful in getting home.

I was prescribed some dice to take today
And let it loose full blown!

> I feel like I might be stretching a bit here, but bear with me... If we choose Rail as the word from the previous step, and add a singular die (you don't want to take too many at a time after all), we can anagram to deliria, which is a full-blown state of wild excitement!

Comment: Very interesting answer, but not what I had in mind. Any time where letters are taken/added, there is a hint for which ones, so you can't just "take away some letters"!

Comment: For an answer that's not what @Oliver had in mind, this is pretty good

Comment: I agree! @Johnson, you have the right idea - try using the hints I've added

Answer (score 0):

> Just a *real* attempt at this one, I could be off, but I think the **Word** in this case is **booze** (alcohol). Some reasoning is that we have a *wooziness* clue in the first paragraph, and the *I mixed it up* basically, to avoid showing the alcohol, you would have to have modify the contents or mixture to make it not smell or look like **booze**. Later, when you got home you were *prescribed dice* meaning, you probably had to take some medication to get over the effects of the **booze**. Cool riddle, but there could probably be more and better answers.

Comment: Interesting answer, but not the one I'm after. These sorts of puzzles are based around anagrams and adding/removing letters